# sympy parser doesn't identify expm1 as a symbolic function

Tags: python, sympy

The function `expm1` is not parsed properly in the following example:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
print parse_expr('expm1(x)').diff('x')
```

gives

```
Derivative(expm1(x), x)
```

How can I get `sympy` identifying `expm1` as symbolic function, so that I get the same result as

```
print parse_expr('exp(x) - 1').diff('x')
```

which gives `exp(x)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no built-in `expm1` in SymPy, the parser does not know anything about this notation. The parameter `local_dict` of `parse_expr` can be used to explain the meaning of unfamiliar functions and symbols to SymPy.

```
expm1 = lambda x: exp(x)-1
parse_expr('expm1(x)', local_dict={"expm1": expm1})
```

This returns `exp(x) - 1`.

For expm1 to remain a single function with known derivative, rather than `exp(x)-1`, define it as a SymPy function (see [tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/guide.html#functions) for more such examples).

```
class expm1(Function):
    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        return exp(self.args[0])
```

A confirmation that this works:

```
e = parse_expr('expm1(x)', local_dict={"expm1": expm1})
print(e)           # expm1(x)
print(e.diff(x))   # exp(x)
f = lambdify(x, e)
print(f(1))        # 1.718281828459045
print(f(1e-20))    # 1e-20, unlike exp(x)-1 which would evaluate to 0
```

Comment: This works, but it is equivalent to writing `exp(x) - 1` in my expression. This solution has the drawback that when I lambdify it uses the `exp` function instead of `expm1`. Is there a way of lambdifying the expression with `expm1` but to differentiate it as it was written in plain `exp(x) - 1`?

Comment: There is actually a definition of `expm1` present in `.codegen.cfunctions`